# Execute a file from nerdTree

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

With the default file explorer (netrw) you can press `x` to open a file or directory with the system default application. Is there an easy way I can do the same with nerdTree? I can't find the option. Thanks.

Comment: You can maybe try `gx` since it's basic Vim functionality and I assume it's worth a shot.

Comment: It works with the files (at least it did open firefox with .html files) so it's something but It would be great if it also worked with folders. Netrw opened nautilus when I executed folders.

Comment: Hmm. But I, and I think you too, have looked through the whole documentation of NERDTree. I guess you can ask the developers directly in their issue tracker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In NERDTree, press `m` to bring up the **NERDTree Menu**, and then you should see an option, labeled `o`, to open the current node with the system editor associated with that file or directory. If that doesn't work for you, create an issue in the [NERDTree repo](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues).